# MySQL PBXT vs InnoDB

Tags: mysql, database, innodb, benchmarking, pbxt

I'm wondering what are are the pros/cons of the new PBXT Engine vs the good old one InnoDB?

Where can I find a list of features and maybe some benchmarks comparing these two DB engines?

Comment: "The reason is that PBXT is not actively maintained anymore. It has a few bugs that are not fixed and it's not actively used." sounds like a show stopper to me.